# RestClientException : No HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, rest, exception

This appears to be a common error, but there also appears to be various solutions.

I have tried a number of them without any luck. The Jackson dependency was added, the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter object was used.  Verified the MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON is being set.

Converting the POJO to a json string first and changing the Controller to accept a String instead of the specific object it works.

The following is a code snippet showing the controller which accepts a POJO and it generates the exception. There were some slight changes and hopefully no syntax errors.

**The Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/main")
public class TestController 
{

    @GetMapping(path="/firstTest", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = "application/json")
    public String login(@RequestBody MyObject1 obj1) 
    {
         System.out.println("============Inside routine=============");
         return "Returning....";
    }
}
```

**The Cosumer**

```
private static void runTest() 
{
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyObject(101, "Test");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("key", "value");
    HttpEntity<MyObject1 > packetEntity = new HttpEntity<>(obj1,headers);

    ResponseEntity<String>result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/main/FirstTest", HttpMethod.GET, packetEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**The Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for com.demo.MyObject1 and content type "application/json"
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586)
    at com.demo.clientSide.SimplestGetExample.attemptLogin(Test.java:106)
    at com.demo.clientSide.SimplestGetExample.main(Test.java:56)
```

**POJO**

```
 import lombok.Data;
 import lombok.Getter;
 import lombok.Setter;

public class MyObject1 
{
    @Setter @Getter int x;
    @Setter @Getter String y;

    public MyObject1() {}


public MyObject1(int x, String y)
    {
        this.x  = x;
        this.y  = y;
    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious that was missed with this example?

Since not completely certain the @RequestBody is required within the Controller.

Should I be able to pass in a POJO and have Spring do the conversion to json behind the scenes or it is expected that I explicitly do the conversion to json?

**Updated Info**

If the following line is commented out a slightly different Exception is received.

```
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

One thread mentioned since this is a GET routine the ContentType shouldn't be set. The exception is basically the same but without the last part of the string "....and content type "application/json"

Comment: Does your POJO not have setters? If not try to add `@JsonCreator` to your constructor and `@JsonValue` to the params. As an alternative create a default constructor and setters.

Comment: And also your exception is thrown by the client and not the controller.

Comment: For the MyObject1 on both client and server, the @ Setter @ Getter is used by importing the lombok package for each Parameter along with a default constructor and it generates the same exception.  I modified the original post with how the POJO now looks.

Comment: I am also getting the same and tried solution mentioned but no luck. @Unhandled you got any solution

Comment: @HiteshKumar  Unfortunately not and it was only a test project I was working and have moved on since, sorry.